# Choosing the right transistor for switching high-power LEDs

Tags: transistors, power, mosfet, led

I'm building a circuit that will turn on high-power LEDs.

I can't seem to figure out which transistor would be the best to turn on dual-color 3 W LEDs with these specs:

- White color:

  - forward voltage: 3.0-3.6 V
  - constant current: 600-700 mA
- Yellow color:

  - forward voltage: 2.0-2.4 V
  - constant current: 600-700 mA

I will use suitable LED drivers to keep the LEDs working on proper voltage and current.

So which transistor would be the best to use to turn on these LEDs?

Comment: LED models with links to datasheets, schematics and pictures in your question would give us something to with, but your question right not is too vague and too broad. Almost any transistor would work at low currents and voltages, but you haven't given us enough to help you with.

Answer (score 2):

Your LEDs need to be driven with constant current so you will need a constant current driver.

The problem with using a transistor to switch the LED at the output of a constant current driver is that, when you turn the transistor off, the driver will still try to maintain constant current, so it will increase output voltage. This will charge the output capacitor inside the driver. When the transistor turns back on, the capacitor discharges through the LED, causing a current spike. In the worst case this can damage the LED. The more common case is that if you use PWM to dim the LED it won't work, because when you use a lower PWM value the driver will compensate by increasing the voltage, so the LED doesn't dim.

So you need to think about the whole system.

For example you can use a driver that can be controlled with an ENABLE input, or a driver with a dimming input that controls output current. Since you have 2 LEDs you would need 2 drivers, or an all-in-one variable color temperature driver. If that's too complicated you can use a constant voltage power supply and control current in the LEDs with resistors the old fashionable way, in this case you can use MOSFETs as switching transistors.